# Comparing string item in one list to string attribute of item in another list

Tags: c#, collections, foreach

I have two lists: one is a collection of strings, the other is a collection of objects that has string attributes. I'm trying to compare something in list 1 to an attribute of something in list 2.
I know how to do it, but the code below looks rather slow, and I was looking for a way to optimize it/do it more cleanly. Below is what I already have:

```
foreach (var a in collectionOne)
{
  foreach (var b in collectionTwo)
  {
    if (a == b.Name)
    {
      //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ofcourse you could do this in LINQ but what are you trying to optimize? what _looks slow_?

Comment: This would be best over at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: @JSteward I thought I could type something with a better runtime than a nested foreach.